# How to create a tuple of types?

Tags: python, shapely

I want to compare the type of a value from an incoming bytestream and want to do an operation based on its type and I would like to use the `isinstance()` method to do this efficiently.

But I am not sure what's the pythonic way to create a tuple of standard datatypes or something like shapely geometry types.

For example, I am doing something as follows:

```
simple_types = (type([]), type('blah'), type(101))
```

Now, If the incoming values are `'hello'` and `64`, then the following code would give me the appropriate boolean value result based on which I could do something:

```
if isinstance(value, simple_types):
    #do something (for the values above, it would come in here)
else:
    #do something
```

Is there any other good way to do this? I actually want to translate this logic to Shapely's geometry types.

Thanks

Comment: Just `(list, string, int)` ?

Comment: `tuple(type([]), type('blah'), type(101))` will give you a TypeError. Maybe you mean `(type([]), type('blah'), type(101))`

Comment: The code you posted does not run. `tuple(type([]), type('blah'), type(101))` is invalid.

Comment: @DeepSpace oh crap! Didn’t knew that ‍♂️

Comment: Maybe even namedtuples might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the types directly, ie

```
if isinstance(value, (list, str, int)):
```